# NullPointerException on getting Button Text within Activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write a simple app that outputs a Toast when clicking on a Button within the layout.  I feel like this is a really simple fix but can't get it to run properly.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button btnSpotifyApp, btnScoresApp, btnLibraryApp, btnBuildItBigger, btnXYZReader, btnCapstone;
private Toast mToast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnSpotifyapp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSpotifyApp);
    Button btnScoresApp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScoresApp);
    Button btnLibraryApp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLibraryApp);
    Button btnBuildItBigger = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBuildItBigger);
    Button btnXYZReader = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnXYZReader);
    Button btnCapstone = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapstone);

    btnSpotifyapp.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnScoresApp.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnLibraryApp.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnBuildItBigger.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnXYZReader.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCapstone.setOnClickListener(this);
}

/**
 * Called when a view has been clicked.
 *
 * @param v The view that was clicked.
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        //SignIn Button Clicked
        case R.id.btnSpotifyApp:
            showToast(btnSpotifyApp.getText().toString());
            break;
        case R.id.btnScoresApp:
            showToast(btnScoresApp.getText().toString());
            break;
        case R.id.btnLibraryApp:
            showToast(btnLibraryApp.getText().toString());
            break;
        case R.id.btnBuildItBigger:
            showToast(btnBuildItBigger.getText().toString());
            break;
        case R.id.btnXYZReader:
            showToast(btnXYZReader.getText().toString());
            break;
        case R.id.btnCapstone:
            showToast(btnCapstone.getText().toString());
            break;
    }
}
```

Here's the full log for it:

```
Process: com.app, PID: 6964
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.Button.getText()' on a null object reference
            at com.app.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:59)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: in `onCreate` it should be `btnSpotifyapp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSpotifyApp);` not `Button btnSpotifyapp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSpotifyApp);`, and this for every button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the button variables that you have already defined before your onCreate() method. Your onCreate() method should look like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

btnSpotifyapp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSpotifyApp);
btnScoresApp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScoresApp);
btnLibraryApp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLibraryApp);
btnBuildItBigger = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBuildItBigger);
btnXYZReader = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnXYZReader);
btnCapstone = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapstone);

btnSpotifyapp.setOnClickListener(this);
btnScoresApp.setOnClickListener(this);
btnLibraryApp.setOnClickListener(this);
btnBuildItBigger.setOnClickListener(this);
btnXYZReader.setOnClickListener(this);
btnCapstone.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: For some reason I was thinking I had to add another 'Button' but you're right I'm not using the ones I'd declared in the class.

Answer (score 2):

you are re-declaring all the buttons inside onCreate, so your class members aren't initialized, so they are null, I'm guessing btnSpotifyApp caused it the first time,

also - try correcting the spelling for:

```
private Button btnSpotifyApp
```

as opposed to :

```
btnSpotifyapp.setOnClickListener(this);
```

try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button btnSpotifyApp, btnScoresApp, btnLibraryApp, btnBuildItBigger, btnXYZReader, btnCapstone;
private Toast mToast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.btnSpotifyApp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSpotifyApp);
    this.btnScoresApp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScoresApp);
    this.btnLibraryApp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLibraryApp);
    this.btnBuildItBigger = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBuildItBigger);
    this.btnXYZReader = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnXYZReader);
    this.btnCapstone = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapstone);

    btnSpotifyApp.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnScoresApp.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnLibraryApp.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnBuildItBigger.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnXYZReader.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCapstone.setOnClickListener(this);
}

/**
 * Called when a view has been clicked.
 *
 * @param v The view that was clicked.
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        //SignIn Button Clicked
        case R.id.btnSpotifyApp:
            showToast(this.btnSpotifyApp.getText().toString());
            break;
        case R.id.btnScoresApp:
            showToast(this.btnScoresApp.getText().toString());
            break;
        case R.id.btnLibraryApp:
            showToast(this.btnLibraryApp.getText().toString());
            break;
        case R.id.btnBuildItBigger:
            showToast(this.btnBuildItBigger.getText().toString());
            break;
        case R.id.btnXYZReader:
            showToast(this.btnXYZReader.getText().toString());
            break;
        case R.id.btnCapstone:
            showToast(this.btnCapstone.getText().toString());
            break;
    }
}
```

also - just wondering - are you trying to get the text that's on the button? or the text from someplace else?

Comment: Just the text from the button for a Toast.  Is there a difference (in this case) from having a preceding 'this.' in the code?

Comment: in your post - Yes, since you have members and  local variables by the same name, in what I wrote - No, since the members are the only variables in the class scope, I added it for clarity :)

Answer (score 1):

check out the scope of variables Button inside the OnCreate() method, you are not initializing the class private Button object fields but creating new buttons inside the scope of the OnCreate().

You should do that:

```
    this.btnSpotifyapp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSpotifyApp);
```